# Burninate the [into] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Reviewing suggested edits, I stumbled across the [into](/questions/tagged/into) tag. To me, it seems it doesn't add any value and can't stand on its own, so it'd be a candidate for burnination. I am, however, not well versed in SQL, so I may be missing something.

Currently there are 84 questions tagged [into](/questions/tagged/into).

Comment: Ah... people writing sentences in the tag box... `:-/`

Comment: Should be done now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily remove the [into](/questions/tagged/into) tag from the questions it's on in < 15 minutes.  I suggest removing the tag manually (it's a garbage tag and adds no meaning) and then the reputation requirements will kick in when someone wants to use it again.

That said, I've added it to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012.

Comment: Yeah, good. I just wanted to make sure it has no hidden value I didn't see before going to work.

Comment: @DanielFischer From what I see, it looks like people typing title names into the tag area =)

Comment: If a tag does not have related questions, it still exists right? So people could still tag questions with `into` by typing complete sentence in the tag box I guess. If that's the case, this tag should be deleted. I assume only new users without the privilege to create new tags are doing something like this.

Comment: @Felix If the tag doesn't have questions, then it requires someone with 1500 rep (on SO) to bring it back (just like new tags).  [I've proposed a feature request to increase the rep required to bring a tag back that people have removed from all questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131585/if-a-tag-existed-and-then-is-removed-raise-reputation-needed-to-add-tag-again)

Comment: @Felix A tag without questions ia auto-removed after a day. If somebody reuses it before that, I guess it could work. I'll keep a tab open to watch for it until tomorrow.